# Monotouch.Dialog - Setting Back Button

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I use the MonoTouch.Dialog DialogViewController to create a nice view.

```
private RootElement _createRoot(){
    return new RootElement ("Buy a Property Report"){

            new Section (""){
                new StringElement ("View Sample", ()=>{ }),
                new StringElement ("Enter Address", ()=>{ }),
                new StringElement ("Locate This House", () => { }),
                new StringElement ("My Reports", () => { })
            } 
        };
}
```

On the following screens I need to have a back button that is different then what I specified in the previous  "Buy a Property Report" to "Home"

I do this.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.Title = "Home";
}
```

**Is there a way to do this in Monotouch.Dialog instead?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you question well but try to use this on the dialog controller:

```
this.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem.Title = "Home";
```

Comment: At what point in the DVC lifecycle do you do this? If I do it in `ViewDidLoad`, BackBarButtonItem is still null. If I do it in `ViewDidAppear`, you can briefly see the default title before it changes to 'Home'.